# Trying to add ads to my app but its not working?

Tags: iphone, admob

I am trying to ad apps but I'm getting this error and i don't know what to do. The app works but the ads don't come up and i think it might have to do with the issue. I am really new to making apps/programming so any help would be much appreciated! Thank you.

Here's the issue that comes up: Apple Mach-O Linker (ID) Warning

```
Ld "/Users/ANavarro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Animal_Sounds_Plus_App-edacugxnhvpqgxblqwcanzgnwdrc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Animal Sounds Plus App.app/Animal Sounds Plus App" normal i386
    cd "/Users/ANavarro/Desktop/Animal Sounds Plus App"
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk -L/Users/ANavarro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Animal_Sounds_Plus_App-edacugxnhvpqgxblqwcanzgnwdrc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator "-L/Users/ANavarro/Desktop/Animal Sounds Plus App/GoogleAdMobAdsSDK" "-L/Users/ANavarro/Desktop/Animal Sounds Plus App" -F/Users/ANavarro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Animal_Sounds_Plus_App-edacugxnhvpqgxblqwcanzgnwdrc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist "/Users/ANavarro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Animal_Sounds_Plus_App-edacugxnhvpqgxblqwcanzgnwdrc/Build/Intermediates/Animal Sounds Plus App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Animal Sounds Plus App.build/Objects-normal/i386/Animal Sounds Plus App.LinkFileList" -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -framework MessageUI -framework SystemConfiguration -framework AVFoundation -framework AudioToolbox -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -lGoogleAdMobAds -o "/Users/ANavarro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Animal_Sounds_Plus_App-edacugxnhvpqgxblqwcanzgnwdrc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Animal Sounds Plus App.app/Animal Sounds Plus App"

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/ANavarro/Desktop/Animal Sounds Plus App/GoogleAdMobAdsSDK'
```

Comment: The "directory not found" warning seems pretty descriptive to me.  You appear to be missing the directory containing the Admob SDK, or you've placed it in a different location from what your project expects.

Comment: i fixed it but thanks anyways!!